# Using the same .then().catch() block for different Promises

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that determines if the browser is IE11 or not. It then resolves that promise by notifying that the password has been copied to the clipboad or failed to save.

But you will notice, that I am using the same code twice (the .then().catch() block are exactly the same). Anyway to condense this?

```
   copyToClipBoard(str) {
        if (this.isIE11()) {
            this.copyToIE11ClipBoard(str)
                .then(() => {
                    eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
                        type: 'info',
                        text: i18n.t('copy'),
                        buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
                    });
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
                        type: 'info',
                        text: i18n.t('copy-fail'),
                        buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
                    });
                });
        } else {
            navigator.clipboard
                .writeText(str)
                .then(() => {
                    eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
                        type: 'info',
                        text: i18n.t('copy'),
                        buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
                    });
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
                        type: 'info',
                        text: i18n.t('copy-fail'),
                        buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
                    });
                });
        }
    },
    isIE11() {
        return !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
    },
    copyToIE11ClipBoard(str) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const password = window.clipboardData.setData('Text', str);
            if (password) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you reuse any value.

Store it in a variable.

```
const myThen = () => {
    eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
        type: 'info',
        text: i18n.t('copy'),
        buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
    });
}
```

Then use the variable.

```
.writeText(str)
.then(myThen)
```

---

Better yet. Don't do all the calls to `then` and `catch` inside the `if/else` branch.

Bring the promise *out* of the `if/else` and have a shared chain of logic for the rest of the code.

At that point, your `if/else` logic becomes "Get the value from one of two function calls depending on an expression" and you can move to a conditional operator.

```
copyToClipBoard(str) {
    const promise = this.isIE11() 
        ? this.copyToIE11ClipBoard(str) 
        : navigator.clipboard.writeText(str);
    promise.then(() => {
        eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
        // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two functions for the success case and failure case.

```
const successFunction= () => {
     eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
          type: 'info',
          text: i18n.t('copy'),
          buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
     });
}

const failureFunction = () => {
     eventBus.$emit('addSnack', {
          type: 'info',
          text: i18n.t('copy-fail'),
          buttonText: i18n.t('ok'),
     });
}
```

in your function,

```
this.copyToIE11ClipBoard(str).then(successFunction),catch(failureFunction);
```